# Same code in JavaScript, different results

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

this is my first question here. I'm learning Javascript, specifically Backbone.js, with the help of [this book](http://rapidprototypingwithjs.com/#section-home), *Rapid Prototyping with JavaScript*, by Azat Mardan.

In chapter 4, the Backbone.js framework is introduced and explain with a tutorial and example. Up to this point, I haven't had problems directly following the book's code. However, I've been trying to copy the example code and it isn't working. When I directly copy the source code from github, though, it inexplicably works.

Here is my code. The author's code can be found at [this link](https://github.com/azat-co/rpjs/blob/master/backbone/binding/index.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="backbone.js"></script>

  <script>
    var appleData = [
      {
        name: "fuji",
        url: "img/fuji.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: "gala",
        url: "img/gala.jpg"
      }
    ];
    var app;
    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'apples/:appleName':'loadApple'
      },
      initialize: function(){
        var apples = new Apples();
        apples.reset(appleData);
        this.homeView = new homeView({collection: apples});
        this.appleView = new appleView({collection: apples});
      },
      home: function(){
        this.homeView.render();
      },
      loadApple: function(appleName){
        this.appleView.loadApple(appleName);
      }
    });

    var homeView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: 'body',
      template: _.template('Apple data: <%= data %>'),
      render: function(){
         this.$el.html(this.template({data: JSON.stringify(this.collection.models)}));
      }
    });
    var Apples = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    });
    var appleView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        this.model = new (Backbone.Model.extend({}));
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.on('spinner', this.showSpinner , this);
      },
      template: _.template('<figure>\
                             <img src="<%= attributes.url %>"/>\
                             <figcaption><%= attributes.name %></figcaption>\
                            </figure>'),
      templateSpinner: '<img src="img/spinner.gif" width="30"/>',
      loadApple: function(appleName){
        this.trigger('spinner');
        var view = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
          view.model.set(view.collection.where({name:appleName})[0].attributes);
        },1000);
      },
      render: function(appleName) {
        var appleHtml = this.template(this.model);
        $('body').html(appleHtml);
      },
      showSpinner: function() {
        $('body').html(this.templateSpinner);
      }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      app = new router;
      Backbone.history.start();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried [DiffNow](http://www.diffnow.com), but the code is exactly the same.

Additional info:

- I use Sublime Text 2 with 2-space tabs.
- I have tried my code in FF and Chrome; it worked in neither.
  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I already solve the error, seems like i had a weird whitespace character in this line

```
showSpinner: function(){
```

between the ) and {

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the console say, any errors?

Comment: @elclanrs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: line 70" this one --> showSpinner: function() {

Comment: that would mean missing comma, are you sure the code you are showing there is not missing a comma? I could not spot such error there.

Comment: In any case that is one of the messier JS snippets that I have seen.

Comment: Indeed 1 possibility is your original code has space after `\` in the line continuations but this would probably lead to another error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy the backslashes (`\`) he's got in his templates, either keep everything on one line or concatenate the strings with `+`. I went ahead and copied your code [here](http://jsbin.com/dasogilo/2) and you can see it work:

- [Fuji](http://jsbin.com/dasogilo/2#apples/fuji)
- [Gala](http://jsbin.com/dasogilo/2#apples/gala)

Here's some more [info](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals) from Google's JavaScript style guide.

Comment: I can't vote up your answer already but thanks, i'll check it that guide!